# what value will be returned by this expression in Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am new to crystal report and I am trying to reverse engineer a report. I came accross one group selection formula in the report. The formula is

```
count({student.studentId}, @grade Name) > 3
```

Here @grade Name is a formula which just replaces grade number with human readable values.

So I was wondering what value would be returned from this? Will it return true or false kind of value or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guess it will return you the number of students of the grade returned by the formula if they grow bigger than three..

Answer (score 2):

That is a group-selection formula--similar to the SQL `HAVING` clause, but with these differences:

- the data isn't removed from the report--it's suppressed
- while the groups are suppressed on the canvas, they are still visible in the "group tree"

It will suppress each {student.student_id} group (and associated details) that has a count > 3.

A group-selection formula must return a `True` or `False` value (explicitly or implicitly, as in this situation).

Comment: Thanks @craig for the reply. It helped me  understand how does it works. Just to clarify the above statement will suppress or in other words will not show group of student ids whose count is less than 3. The group will be displayed when conditions is evaluated to False and not true. Let me know if I am right in my understanding.